# restarting Intersystem Cache for lockout time

Tags: caching, admin, intersystems-cache

Hi is it possible to restart the database from the management portal.

I'm trying to increase the lockout time do I need to restart the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restart, only in manual mode. It is impossible to do via Managment portal.